# Python: Basic program to drop an image

Tags: python

I am just trying to learn **python gaming** and I just tried to drop a image on the screen by using the below code but I am unable to do it. Can any one tell me where I have done the mistake? Thanks in advance.

```
import sys,os,pygame
from livewires import games,colour
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
x=320
y=320
class apple(games.Sprite):
    def __init__sprite(screen,x,y,image,dx,dy):
        x+=dx
        y+=dy
        print(x)
        print(y)
        self.init_sprite(my_screen,x,y,"G:\\Documents and Settings\\SAI\\Desktop\\py2.2\\apple.PNG")


my_screen=games.Screen(640,640)
image=games.load_image("G:\\Documents and     Settings\\SAI\\Desktop\\py2.2\\bg.JPG",transparent = 0)
my_screen.set_background(image)
games.Text(my_screen,500,40,"Score:0",50,colour.black)
scrollimage=games.load_image("G:\\Documents and Settings\\SAI\\Desktop\\py2.2\\apple.PNG",transparent = 0)
for i in range(0,6):
    apple(my_screen,x,y,scrollimage,80,0)

my_screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I strongly suggest to read up on a few tutorials. I see a general lack of understanding of the whole object-oriented principle as well as how classes work in Python and how to update them.
Also the combination with livewires is needless. Pygame offers what you need to do.
I found these here very helpful when I started:
http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2010/09/01/the-top-10-pygame-tutorials/
In general: Anything by Eli Bendersky and Al Sweigart is really useful for a beginner.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will read this Tutorials .

Comment: You're welcome, we all started there